# Как правильно трактовать следующее предложение?

Tags: правила

*"При положительных результатах поверки на прибор, пломбу или в паспорте (документе его заменяющем), наносят поверительное клеймо."*

Здесь говорится о том, что при положительных результатах поверки необходимо нанести поверительное клеймо на прибор и пломбу, либо в паспорт, или же здесь говорится о том, что клеймо необходимо нанести либо на прибор, либо на пломбу, либо в паспорт?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

"При положительных результатах поверки на прибор, пломбу или в паспорте (документе, его заменяющем) наносят поверительное клеймо".

Предлагается три варианта постановки клейма.

Это однородные обстоятельства с **замыкающим союзом ИЛИ.** Из правил Лопатина: Если последний член ряда присоединяется союзами и, да, или, то запятая перед ним не ставится.

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря, считаю, что если дело важное, то Вам лучше всего уточнить это у автора инструкции/в соответствующем ведомстве, а не у лингвиста/на сайте в интернете. Языковые правила тут вторичны по сравнению с официальным предписанием. Написано довольно неоднозначно.

При этом, если опираться исключительно на лингвистику, то я соглашусь с предыдущими ответами, правильная трактовка - поставьте одну пломбу в одно из трёх предложенных мест.

Но, повторюсь, не факт, что писавший имел в виду именно то, что написал. Частенько подобные инструкции составляются довольно косноязычными людьми или же просто без надлежащего внимания к деталям.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, здесь говорится о том, что *клеймо необходимо нанести либо на прибор, либо на пломбу, либо в паспорт*. Если бы в предложении говорилось о том, что клеймо нужно нанести *на прибор и пломбу либо в паспорт*, то между словами **прибор** и **пломба** стоял союз **и**, а не запятая.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с предыдущими.
С точки зрения логики наиболее правдоподобным выглядит соображение, что пытались сформулировать "в одно из трех мест". Только запятая после скобок получилась лишняя - и из-за неё определенные сомнения.

А вот что там в реале имелось в виду - это надо у авторов уточнять, поскольку сама идея такой "альтернативной" маркировки мне не очень нравится. По идее-то подобные оттиски или клейма ставят во всех трех из перечисленных мест. Но в каждом ведомстве, видимо, могут быть свои подходы.